# Check if any modal is running

Tags: python, scripting

I have pie menus that conflict with the keymap of other addons when being in some of their modal operators.

Is there a way to check if there is any modal running and use that as a poll for my pie menus?

Comment: Not sure how helpful this is; `bpy.ops.script.reload()` throws an error when a modal timer is running.

Comment: Unfortunately it takes a couple of seconds to try `bpy.ops.script.reload()`, not really suitable to open a pie menu.